# Google Cloud Storage: Uploaded image is corrupt

Tags: java, image, google-cloud-storage

I am uploading an image to my bucket in my google cloud storage with the following code:

```
        File file = new File("test.jpg");

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/imagecachebucket/o?uploadType=media&name=test.jpg&projection=full");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");

        FileBody fileB = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");

        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();        
        multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        multipartEntity.addPart("file", fileB);
        httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
        System.out.println( "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine( ) );
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httppost );
            System.out.println("response: " + response.getStatusLine().toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( );
```

The image is uploaded, i can see it in the cloud storage browser, but when i want to view the image, it is broken, there is only the standard icon for a non viewable image. When i upload the image over the cloud storage browser, the image is uploaded correctly.

Comment: Hi - I haven't used the Apache lib you're using, but some questions/suggestions: (a) does the object size (from either the Cloud Storage browser or gsutil) match the size of the file you uploaded? (b) What happens if you use a different HttpMultipartMode, like STRICT?

Comment: The size is the same. With STRICT it is the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're doing a multipart upload of exactly 1 part, but you've specified the uploadType to be "media".

The media upload type is for the case where you are simply uploading a file. In that case, Google Cloud Storage expects the whole of the body to be the object that is being uploaded.

If you want to do a multipart upload, that's fine. For that, you should use the upload type "multipart." Multipart uploads expect two parts, where the first part is the object's metadata (permissions, custom user metadata, etc) and the second part is the data.

There's exact documentation for each type of upload type here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/media_upload

My HttpClient-fu isn't very good, but I think that a "media" case would look more like this:

```
FileEntity entity = new FileEntity(file, 
ContentType.create("text/plain", "UTF-8"));        
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/imagecachebucket/o?uploadType=media&name=test.jpg&projection=full");
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```