# Google cloud storage uploaded via node, image is broken

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Appears images uploaded using node library appear to be broken though they report the right size.

A similar issue was reported regarding using [Java/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924389/google-cloud-storage-uploaded-image-is-corrupt)

```
    let fileName: string = `public/static/${data["name"]}`;
    let file: Storage.File = this.bucket.file(fileName);

    var fileBuffer = Buffer.from(data["source"], 'base64');

    return from(file.save(fileBuffer, { contentType: data["contentType"], public: data["isPublic"] }))
        .pipe(map(() => {
            return { source: `${this.publicURLPrefix}/${fileName}` }
        }));
```

With the above code, image file is successfully upload, code converts base64 uploaded content and writes to file specified. However upon browsing to public URL the image appears corrupted/broken. Manually uploaded image works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

tired solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110294/nodejs-base64-image-encoding-decoding-not-quite-working) regarding node storing broken images, and it appears meta information in base64encoded image needs to be removed. Updated working code below

```
    let fileName: string = `${namespace}/${data["name"]}`;
    let file: Storage.File = this.bucket.file(fileName);

    //add acl, who has access to this file
    console.debug("creating/modifying file", fileName);

    let base64Source = (data["source"] as string).replace(/^data:image\/(png|gif|jpeg);base64,/,'');
    let fileBuffer = new Buffer(base64Source,'base64');

    return from(file.save(fileBuffer, { contentType: data["contentType"], public: data["isPublic"] }))
        .pipe(map(() => {
            return { source: `${this.publicURLPrefix}/${fileName}` }
        }));
```